# Resources for evidence-based development practices

Tags: oop

I am interested in studies and papers detailing trials that explore the evidence for different development practices in object-oriented languages. I am particularly keen on studies that measure productivity or consider the influence of modern IDEs. Can you point recommend any good resources for this? Has much work been done in this area of late?

Answer (score 1):

For better or worse, empirically-driven productivity metrics are synonymous with Agile these days.

One that looks interesting for (shockingly) the agile research paper list
http://www.agilealliance.org/index.php/download_file/view/18/

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though this is an [ongoing research area](http://www.dur.ac.uk/ebse/).